# Adding background image to R Markdown (.rmd) file for PDF output?

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

Is it possible to add a background image to a R Markdown (.rmd) file for PDF output?

I have scoured through [Pandoc's R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#images) documentation but cannot find any mention of adding a background image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex): save the following as `header.tex` (replacing image.jpg by the path to your background image):

```
\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.4,
angle=0,
pages=all,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{image.jpg}
  }%
}
```

And add to your yaml:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---
```

See the [`background` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) for tips on how to customize the output.

Comment: Hi, super useful. I implemented it as well but I have still some small margins left and right, so the background is not scaled over the complete width of the document. I checked for the geometry package but no changes were applied to the image when setting the margins to 0. Do you have a hint for me here? Thanks!