# How to add the background image only in first page of pdf output of rmarkdown? and how to add watermark in each page of pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to add background image only to first page of pdf output of Rmarkdown also needs to set opacity of the image so that the text font color is visible clearly.

Secondly, I want to add watermark to each page of pdf considering plots/graphs in pdf.

How do I do that?

Any help in this regard will be very helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?, what are your programming problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043187/adding-background-image-to-r-markdown-rmd-file-for-pdf-output  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748248/watermark-in-rmarkdown I took help of these link but was not able to add background image to first page of pdf

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example to show the approach you are taking so that it is possible to see what is happening and possibly suggest a resolution? [MRE]